SonarQube build step fails with "Error : The specified iOS provisioning profile Distribution_AdHoc' could not be found" in Azure DevOps
I'm trying to build Sonar in azure mobile pipeline, but I'm getting the error listed below.
"Error: The specified iOS provisioning profile Distribution_AdHoc' could not be found" occurs during the SonarQube build step. I would like to exclude this AD-Hoc certificate from the build stage.
I tried a few argument and parameters to bypass the certificate, but it didn't work.

Hi there, Welcome to SO, can you share your YAML definition context to help understand the current workflow? Were your trying to scan a xcode project with SonarQube via pipelines? Have your reached out to their support community as those extensions are published and maintained by their support? Thx.
